# Query to select current and previous hour, day and month

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

I'm not so good in sql, so i want to know if this statements are correct for selecting curent and previous hour, day, and month?

```
DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL '1' HOUR) <= ADDTIME(Datestamp, Timestamp)
DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL '1' DAY) <= ADDTIME(Datestamp, Timestamp)
DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL '1' MONTH) <= ADDTIME(Datestamp, Timestamp)
```

For example if now 14:49 then i need to count:

1. all from 14:00 to 15:00 (or just until 14:49) - `DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL '0' HOUR) <= ADDTIME(Datestamp, Timestamp)`
2. all from 13:00 to 14:00 `DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL '1' HOUR) <= ADDTIME(Datestamp, Timestamp)`

An the same from day and moth, for example if current is 2013-01-08, then i need to count 2013-01-08 and 2013-01-07

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is an example of how you can use [MySQL date functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html) to create dates:

```sql
SELECT 
    NOW() AS CurrentDateTime, 
    DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00') AS CurrentHour, 
    DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00') - INTERVAL 1 HOUR AS PreviousHour, 
    CURDATE() AS CurrentDate, 
    CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY AS PreviousDate, 
    DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-01') AS CurrentMonth, 
    DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-01') - INTERVAL 1 MONTH AS PreviousMonth
```

Output:

```
CurrentDateTime: 2013-01-08 21:00:51
    CurrentHour: 2013-01-08 21:00:00
   PreviousHour: 2013-01-08 20:00:00
    CurrentDate: 2013-01-08
   PreviousDate: 2013-01-07
   CurrentMonth: 2013-01-01
  PreviousMonth: 2012-12-01
```

And here is example usage:

```
-- SELECT PREVIOUS HOUR ROWS
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE ADDTIME(Datestamp, Timestamp) >= DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00') - INTERVAL 1 HOUR
AND   ADDTIME(Datestamp, Timestamp) <  DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00')

-- SELECT CURRENT HOUR ROWS
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE ADDTIME(Datestamp, Timestamp) >= DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00')
```

Likewise for other cases.

Answer (score 3):

Current plus previous hour:

```
ADDTIME(Datestamp, Timestamp) BETWEEN ADDDATE(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL HOUR(NOW())-1 HOURS) AND NOW()
```

Today plus yesterday:

```
ADDTIME(Datestamp, Timestamp) BETWEEN DATE(DATE_ADD(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL -1 DAY)) AND NOW()
```

Edit: Added individual queries

Current hour (including future):

```
ADDTIME(Datestamp, Timestamp) >= ADDDATE(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL HOUR(NOW()) HOURS)
```

Last hour:

```
DateStamp = DATE(NOW()) AND HOUR(Timestamp) = HOUR(NOW())
```

Current day:

```
Datestamp = DATE(NOW())
```

Last day:

```
Datestamp = DATE(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 DAY))
```

Comment: as i said before i need current - `from 14:00 to 15:00` and previous - `from 13:00 to 14:00`, not sum of it, just 2 int.

Answer (score 0):

The Right Way to get the beginning of the current hour is:

```
SUBDATE(SUBDATE(SUBDATE(NOW(),
        INTERVAL EXTRACT(MICROSECOND FROM NOW()) MICROSECOND),
        INTERVAL EXTRACT(SECOND FROM NOW()) SECOND),
        INTERVAL EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM NOW()) MINUTE))
```

So to get a full hour range you will do something like

```
SUBDATE(SUBDATE(SUBDATE(SUBDATE(NOW(),
        INTERVAL EXTRACT(MICROSECOND FROM NOW()) MICROSECOND),
        INTERVAL EXTRACT(SECOND FROM NOW()) SECOND),
        INTERVAL EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM NOW()) MINUTE),
        INTERVAL 1 HOUR) <= my_date
    AND my_date < SUBDATE(SUBDATE(SUBDATE(NOW(),
        INTERVAL EXTRACT(MICROSECOND FROM NOW()) MICROSECOND),
        INTERVAL EXTRACT(SECOND FROM NOW()) SECOND),
        INTERVAL EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM NOW()) MINUTE)
```

This is actually so painful that if you’re not too much into data type purity, you will use tricks with formatting to get the current hour:

```
STR_TO_DATE(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y%m%d%H'), '%Y%m%d%H') <= my_date
AND my_date <= ADDDATE(STR_TO_DATE(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y%m%d%H'), '%Y%m%d%H'), INTERVAL 1 HOUR)
```

and the preceding hour:

```
SUBDATE(STR_TO_DATE(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y%m%d%H'), '%Y%m%d%H'), INTERVAL 1 HOUR) <= my_date
AND my_date < STR_TO_DATE(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y%m%d%H'), '%Y%m%d%H')
```

the current day:

```
STR_TO_DATE(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y%m%d'), '%Y%m%d') <= my_date
AND my_date <= ADDDATE(STR_TO_DATE(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y%m%d'), '%Y%m%d'), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

and the preceding day:

```
SUBDATE(STR_TO_DATE(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y%m%d'), '%Y%m%d'), INTERVAL 1 DAY) <= my_date
AND my_date < STR_TO_DATE(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y%m%d'), '%Y%m%d')
```

the current month:

```
STR_TO_DATE(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y%m'), '%Y%m') <= my_date
AND my_date <= ADDDATE(STR_TO_DATE(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y%m'), '%Y%m'), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```

and the preceding month:

```
SUBDATE(STR_TO_DATE(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y%m'), '%Y%m'), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) <= my_date
AND my_date < STR_TO_DATE(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y%m'), '%Y%m')
```

Comment: I don't think that is correct way `SUBDATE(SUBDATE(SUBDATE(NOW(),
        INTERVAL EXTRACT(MICROSECOND FROM NOW()) MICROSECOND),
        INTERVAL EXTRACT(SECOND FROM NOW()) SECOND),
        INTERVAL EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM NOW()) MINUTE))`, because you have 4 different NOW() datetime. Really, they certainly can be different.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan No, it is specified that “`NOW()` returns a constant time that indicates the time at which the statement began to execute” http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now